# What is the API to run UI Scripts on Microsoft AppCenter test cloud - Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-test-cloud, visual-studio-app-center

Does anyone have any idea of the API to run UI scripts on Microsoft app center?

I tried `https://api.mobile.azure.com/v0.1/apps/{owner_name}/{app_name}/test_runs/{test_run_id}/report`
from https://openapi.appcenter.ms/#/ but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone have any idea of the API to run UI scripts on Microsoft app center?

Initiating a test run in Test Cloud requires the App Center CLI tool.

https://github.com/Microsoft/appcenter-cli

```
appcenter test status   Checks the status of the started test run
appcenter test stop Stop the started test run
appcenter test generate appium  Generates an Appium project
appcenter test generate uitest  Generates a Xamarin.UITest project
appcenter test prepare appium   Creates an artifacts directory with Appium tests
appcenter test prepare calabash Creates an artifacts directory with Calabash tests
appcenter test prepare espresso Creates an artifacts directory with Espresso tests
appcenter test prepare uitest   Creates an artifacts directory with Xamarin UI Tests
appcenter test prepare xcuitest Creates an artifacts directory with XCUITest tests
appcenter test run appium   Starts a test run with Appium tests
appcenter test run calabash Starts a test run with Calabash tests
appcenter test run espresso Starts a test run with Espresso tests
appcenter test run manifest Starts a test run with previously prepared artifacts
appcenter test run uitest   Starts a test run with Xamarin UI Tests
appcenter test run xcuitest Starts a test run with XCUITest tests
```